# In the matrix P(N,M) (N<=10; M<=15), swap the minimum and maximum elements of each row

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote the code in pascal, but when rewriting it in C++, it does not work.
When you try to replace the maximum with the minimum and back, the maximum element simply disappears. I don't understand what this is connected with. Rewrote the code a bunch of times.

Pascal

```
uses crt;
const nmax=10;
mmax=15;
var a:array[1..nmax,1..mmax] of integer;
m,n,i,j,jmn,jmx:byte;
x:integer;
begin
write('Количество строк до ',nmax,' n=');
readln(n);
write('Количество столбцов до ',mmax,' m=');
readln(m);
writeln('Исходная матрица:');
for i:= 1 to n do
for j:=1 to m do
readln(a[i,j]);
for i:=1 to n do
begin
jmn:=1;jmx:=1;
for j:=1 to m do
begin
if a[i,j]<a[i,jmn] then jmn:=j;
if a[i,j]>a[i,jmx] then jmx:=j;
end;
x:=a[i,jmn];
a[i,jmn]:=a[i,jmx];
a[i,jmx]:=x;
end;
writeln('Обмен максимальных и минимальных в строках:');
for i:=1 to n do
begin
for j:=1 to m do
write(a[i,j]:4);
writeln;
end;
end.
```

Comment: С++
for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
for (j=1;j<=m;j++)
{
std::cout«"a["«i«"]["«j«"]=";
std::cin»a[i][j];
}
jmn = a[1][1];
for (i = 1; i <=n; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <=m; j++)
{
if (a[i][j] < jmn) jmn = a[i][j];
}
jmx = a[1][1];
for (i = 1; i <=n; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <=m; j++)
{
if (a[i][j] > jmx) jmx = a[i][j];
}
}
std::cout « "MIN: " « jmn « std::endl « "MAX: " « jmx « std::endl;

for (i = 1; i <=n; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <=m; j++)
{
if (a[i][j] == jmn) a[i][j] = jmx;
}
}
for (i = 1; i <=n; i++)
{
for (j = 1; j <=m; j++)
{
if (a[i][j] == jmx) a[i][j] = jmn;
}
}

Comment: Is that a Unicode `'«'` character? In C++ you need `<<`, two ASCII characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m, rowMax, rowMin;
    int nmax = 10, mmax = 15;
    cout << "Количество строк до ," << nmax << " n=";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Количество столбцов до ," << mmax << " m=";
    int array[n][m];
    cout<< "Исходная матрица:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cin >> array[i][j];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        rowMax = 1;
        rowMin = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (array[i][j] < array[i][rowMin])
                rowMin = j;
            if (array[i][j] > array[i][rowMax])
                rowMax = j;
        }
        swap(array[i][rowMax], array[i][rowMin]);
    }
    cout<< "Обмен максимальных и минимальных в строках:"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            cout << array[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```